# Express each of these Boolean functions using the operators ·and ¬.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-verification, boolean-algebra

I want to verify my solution for 
$x(x+\bar{y}+\bar{z})\\=xx+\bar{y}x+\bar{z}x\ \text{by Distributive laws}\\
=x+\bar{y}x+\bar{z}x\ \text{by Idempotent laws}\\
=x+\bar{z}x\ \text{by Absorption laws}\\
=x\ \text{by Absorption laws}$

(N.B. I donte $\neg x := \bar{x}$) Is this solution correct?

Comment: What are $x,y,z?$ Please explain your notation: what does $\bar x$ and $\cdot$ mean? What does the title has to do with the content of the question?

Comment: the tite is the requirment for the problem i can't see what is vague for you

Comment: @M.Winter x(x+y¯+z¯) is the boolean function i need to express it

Comment: Assuming $+$ is OR and $\cdot$ (or concatenation) is AND, it looks okay to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks good.

For your information, the other absorption law is $$x(x+w) = x,$$ so your simplification result is right by letting 
$$w = \bar y + \bar z.$$

Comment: the only question is wheter that solution satisfies the requirment of expressing each of the funciton using · (AND) and ¬ (NOT) operators?

Comment: @ErikHambardzumyan Your solution does not contain *any* operator, so its satisfied.